# Getting all values of a multi select dropdown on Click of a button

Tags: jquery

I am using the below lines of code to get all the values of a dropdown id- assigne.

```js
$("#assigne option:selected").each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  if ($this.length) {
    var selText = $this.text();
    console.log(selText);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row form-inline" style="padding-left:10px">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="form-group is-filled">
      <h5>Assigned </h5>
      <select id="assigne" multiple="multiple" style="width:200px;">
                                         <option value="gnanadeep.bitra">Gnanadeep</option>
                                         <option value="nimish.vaibhav">Nimish</option>
                                         <option value="srividya.dommeti">Srividya</option>
                                         <option value="shrutika.agrawal">Shrutika</option>
                                         <option value="srinilaya.pemmaraju">Nilaya</option>
                                         <option value="nishath">Nishath</option>
                                         <option value="ravikiran.kothamasu">Ravi Kiran</option>
                                         <option value="swami.sukumaran">Swami</option>
                                      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But I am getting an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'each' of null

Comment: check the id of the select also check if there are selected option

Comment: checked. the id of select is -assigne. Also, i m selecting values

Comment: Please add the relevant HTML of `#assigne`.

Comment: did you have it in change event of the select? can you add all relevant code

Comment: Are you sure it's this code causing the problem? I ask as it's not possible for a jQuery object to be null.

Comment: show your relevant html too

Comment: Your code  works  properly. http://jsfiddle.net/et3hH/222/.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your modified code:

```js
$("#submit").on('click', function() {
  var foo = [];
  $('#assigne :selected').each(function(i, selected) {
    foo[i] = $(selected).text();
  });
  console.log(foo);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row form-inline" style="padding-left:10px">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="form-group is-filled">
      <h5>Assigned </h5>
      <select id="assigne" multiple="multiple" style="width:200px;">
        <option value="gnanadeep.bitra">Gnanadeep</option>
        <option value="nimish.vaibhav">Nimish</option>
        <option value="srividya.dommeti">Srividya</option>
        <option value="shrutika.agrawal">Shrutika</option>
        <option value="srinilaya.pemmaraju">Nilaya</option>
        <option value="nishath">Nishath</option>
        <option value="ravikiran.kothamasu">Ravi Kiran</option>
        <option value="swami.sukumaran">Swami</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button id="submit">Save</button>
```

Reference: [jQuery Tip – Getting Select List Values](http://marcgrabanski.com/jquery-select-list-values/)

Comment: How changing `option:selected` to `:selected` will help? `.each` will still error.

Comment: got an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'each' of null"

Comment: Well, thats kinda not possible. Please share your HTML to understand the issue.

Comment: Shared the HTML.

Comment: @ShrutikaAgrawal - Tried my code with your HTML and it works.

Comment: thanks. i don't know why is not working in client script.

Comment: Might be some typo in ID or something.